# Unbiased estimator of $P(X\leq 2)$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, parameter-estimation

We are given a random sample of size $n$ from an exponential distribution: $f(x;\theta)= \frac{1}{\theta} \exp{(-x/\theta)} I_{\{0,\infty\}}(x)$. Where $I_{\{0,\infty\}}(x)$ is the indicator function.

Then, my book says that it is "clear" that $I_{\{0,2\}}(x)$ is an unbiased estimator of $P(X\leq2)$.

How is it that this is so clear?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what this indicator variable is? If you do, then taking expectation you will find your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I have the intuition of what is going on, but maybe I think I'm missing some formality in my thoughts. So, could you please check this out:

I think that the indicator is 1 if  $0<X<2$ and 0, else. Then, the expectation would be $E[ I_{\{0<X<2  \}}] = 1 \times P(X\leq 2) + 0 \times P(x > 2)  $, therefore, $E[ I_{\{0<X<2  \}}] = P(X\leq 2) $. My concern is this to be a trivial result? In any case, is it correct? then why is it unbiased? thanks!

Comment: It is a trivial result once you know it. As for why it is unbiased, seems like you don't know what it means for a statistic to be an unbiased estimator of something.

Comment: I was hoping for an explanation and help..

Comment: Only help I can offer is to ask you to check your definitions.